# How do I navigate the design window in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I've been using Android Studio for quite a while, but recently upgraded to the latest version.  I'm now having all kinds of trouble navigating the design window when creating a layout.

Firstly, there's a little floating toolbar, which seems to be the same as the actual toolbar - you can see it in the screenshot below; the one that has "Nexus 4", "AppTheme" and "Default (en-us)". How can I get rid of that? [image: screenshot]

Secondly, there no longer seems to be a way to zoom in/out on my design. I think there used to be something that let me set the % zoom.  Is there a way to do that now?

Finally, the bottom scrollbar (the horizontal one) disappears when it's not in use, but I can't figure out how to get it back.  Sometimes it seems to reappear by magic, but I don't know what I'm doing to make that happen.

I can't find anywhere to change any of this, but it's causing real issues because I can't see part of my design.

Answer (score 1):

1. Why do you want this Toolbar to disappear? It is useful in `Design` view. You can select Design or Text tab at the bottom. This Toolbar helps you to see your layout for different APIs, rotate it, refresh. If you mean two equal buttons, I don't know how to remove them.
2. Well, that Toolbar already has zoom controls (but not on your screeshot). You can use a common way to zoom: Ctrl + Mouse wheel.
3. Yes, it really disappears when nothing to scroll left or right. If not, probably you should reinstall AS.

Comment: It disappeared after an update - has gone back to being the fixed in place one, which works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! Sharon, I didn't understand, has Android Studio fixed problems with Toolbar?

Comment: I'm not sure - but it seems to be resolved.  I don't know whether AS fixed it, or whether my install had a glitch that was fixed when it updated.

Comment: Well, sounds nice. Good luck!